# snmpd.conf network range not accepted

Tags: snmp

I am using snmpd on CentOS 6.3 and was giving a network range to the source for mapping community to security group.

> com2sec mynetwork  192.168.0.0/23  centreon

Anyhow it is not working and I always get a timeout from the polling server.
When I enter the exact ip of the polling server it works (192.168.3.180)

It even works if I enter the whole netmask (255.255.252.0)

Anyhow it should work according to documentation. Did I do anything wrong?